# Bootstrap side menu three levels collapsing

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, side-menu

I'm using SB Admin bootstrap theme and I have problems with collapsing left side menu correctly.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Top level 1 (this one collapses correctly)<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                    <li> Second level 1</li>
                    <li> Second level 2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Top level 2 (This one stays open)<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Second level 1<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
                            <li>Third level 1</li>
                            <li>Third level 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Second level 2<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
                            <li>Third level 1</li>
                            <li>Third level 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-fw"></i> Top level 3 (this one stays open)<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Second level 1<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
                            <li>Third level 1</li>
                            <li>Third level 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> Second level 2<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-third-level collapse">
                            <li>Third level 1</li>
                            <li>Third level 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to acheive is when I first load page the menu should be collapsed. When I select a subitem I want the menu to load collapsed and then open to the correct item. Currently Top menu item with 1 sublevel collapses correctly. The second and third top level first collapse (which is ok) but then open (should stay closed unless a subitem is selected). Third level works ok. What is the correct combination of bootstrap collapse classes to acheive the correct function?

Comment: I am not 100% sure that this is your problem, but take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092984/jquery-animate-a-three-levels-menu?rq=1) which is quite the same problem as yours. I hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, thanks. No this is not the same problem. I'm not writing my own JS. I use bootstrap.js. I know bootstrap has collapse, collapse in, collapsed, active, classes. What I want to know is what is the correct combination of these classes to acheive the correct display.